# Mongodb setup in symfony2 - "Expected array, but got string" in config file

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing my first steps with mongodb in symfony 2.4, following the manual instructions [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html).
After successfully setting up and running mongodb server, I am trying to generate my first getters and setters with the following instruction:

```
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AcmeDemoBundle
```

But all I get is this error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException] 
Invalid type for path "doctrine_mongodb.connections.default_database". 
Expected array, but got string
```

Here is what seems to be my conflicting configuration:

```
# Doctrine Mongo DB Configuration
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: mongodb://localhost:27017
      options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
      default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

namely:

```
default_database: test_database
```

It sounds strange that a default database is expected to be an array. I tried this anyway

```
default_database: [ test_database ]
```

and got this other error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Unrecognized options "0" under "doctrine_mongodb.connections.default_database"
```

[This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html) post about mongdb doctrine configuration gives a lot of info about more advanced options. I tried another database name:

```
default_database: hello_%kernel.environment%
```

with no more luck (got the first error message).

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? Any hint will be welcome ! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful with yml the indentation is "strict". `default_database` must be at the same hierarchical place that `connections`. (Sorry for English).

```
# Doctrine Mongo DB Configuration
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: mongodb://localhost:27017
      options: {}
  default_database: test_database
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, ok, I got it right... so "default_database" should be nested at the same level as "connections"... That was not too difficult :/

```
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: mongodb://localhost:27017
      options: {}
  default_database: test_database
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
```